# Trying to deploy django app to AWS EC2 instance using Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a django app on AWS EC2 and also using gunicorn and Nginx in the process, I followed this tutorial [link](https://dev.to/rmiyazaki6499/deploying-a-production-ready-django-app-on-aws-1pk3). I'm not sure what is going wrong, this is the first time I've used AWS EC2, when I try to launch the IP address of the instance it comes back as:

"can't open page because safari can't establish secure connection to the server"

in my aws console the EC2 'instance state' shows it's running

it has been setup in ubuntu 18.04 , I've also set up security groups in my EC2 instance with http, https, 443, 80, 8000, 5432 and 22 all allowed from any ip address except the 22 which only has my ip address as access. Also in my django app settings 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' , i've added the instance ip address and also '*'.

this is my gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and my gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=djangoadmin
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/djangoapp1 /
ExecStart=/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
djangoapp1.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

ngnix conf file :

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443;
server_name **.***.***.*;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
root /home/ubuntu/djangoapp1;
}

location /media/ {
root /home/ubuntu/djangoapp1;    
}

location / {
include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}
}
```

I check the gunicorn socket with :

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket
```

and it shows it running fine

I've also created a nginx conf file :

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/djangoapp1
```

and linked it with :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/djangoapp1 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

then restarted the nginx server:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

still nothing works!  would appreciate any help

Comment: You need to break down the problem.  When you say "nothing works", you should instead  go through each of the components and check how you can verify if it works.  Does gunicorn come up?  Looking at just your error message and your nginx config, I don't see you turning on SSL within nginx, but you seem to be attempting to use it in the browser.

Comment: on AWS the EC2 instance state shows 'running' , I've checked the gunicorn status with : 'sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket' , and that seems to be fine it says' listening on gunicorn socket' , i also did these 3 commands as instructed in the tutorial : % sudo ufw enable
% sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
% sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full',

Comment: Go on to the instance and try `curl -k https://my-private-ip:443`.  Once you have that working, you can work on getting it working remotely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Wrong server_name configuration in the nginx config

Did you assign an elastic IP address to your EC2 instance?

Select EC2 instance> Actions>Networking> Manage Ip Addresses. Then use option "To add or edit an IPv4 public IP Allocate an Elastic IP to this instance or network interface".

Create an elastic IP
Navigate to Elastic IP address link> click Associate IP
Select the instance to associate IP and save.
Now you will have EC2 instance with public IP without restarting/deleting EC2 instance.

Without this your EC2 instance won't be available outside the Aws network.

It costs money so make sure to check pricing.

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't mention ,  I've already setup the elastic IP.

Comment: Can you ping your instance?

Comment: In the nginx conf file , under 'server_name' , do I give the public or private ip address of the ec2 instance ?

Comment: server_name defaults to an empty string, which is fine; you can exclude it completely.

Comment: thanks , I removed the Nginx conf :  server_name ip address and it worked.